# How is it possible to get IntelliSense working on VSCode for Unity3D on linux?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04

I just started with Unity recently, and because I also use VSCode in my studies, I want to use it for Unity as well.
Unfortunately getting it going is not that easy (for me). 
 

**OS - Ubuntu 18.04 

Unity - 2020.3.9f1 

VSCode - 1.56.2 

Mono - 6.12.0.122 

Dotnet - 3.1.409 & 5.0.300**

For VSCode I got the extentions: *"C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)", "Debugger for Unity", "Unity Code Snippets", "CS-Script" and "Auto-Using for C#"*.

The problem: I do not get the  information/autocomplete IntelliSense should provide. I tried to fix it with several other guides on stackoverflow, ubuntuusers and reddit.. unfortunately no success.
Thank's for helping me.

Comment: Furthermore its not possible for me, to choose vscode as External Script Editor in Unitys menu... dropdownmenu just shows me "open by file extension" and browse.

Answer (score 0):

Unity > Package Manager > VS Code > Upgrade

It's not entirely sure, but when you do that, it has to happen.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Looked it up: It says Visual Studio Code Editor 1.2.3 is currently Installed.